# Google apps API giving "Domain cannot use API." Error

Tags: api, provisioning, google-apps

With [Google Apps API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#creating_labels), While trying to automate the process of label creation

I was able to authenticate & get Auth token, but giving  a post call for

> POST https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain name}/{username}/label

is giving "**Domain cannot use API.**"

**Note:** Provisioning API is already enabled.

**Note:** Am trying this on a Google Apps account came free with buying a domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not available for the free domains.  Upgrade your domain to a premiere to access this API.

See http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=175190&topic=28605&ctx=topic